# Html Code not redirecting user to Shoppy and not showing custom domain after being clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, redirect, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a web page that allows users to create their own cryptocurrency faucet. However, I am facing an issue where the code is not redirecting the user to Shoppy and not showing the custom domain after being clicked.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue? I would appreciate suggestions or insights on how to resolve this problem. Thank you very much!

Here is the html code of my website

```
https://pastebin.com/22KNVHNA
```

This is the html code on the webserver: https://faucethost.me

Here are some things that I have tried:

```
Included necessary scripts in my HTML file: I have included jQuery, Bootstrap CSS/JS files, and the Shoppy embed.js file using CDN links. I have verified that the links are correct and that all files are properly loaded.
Verified event listeners: I have added two event listeners for the dropdown menu and "Get Started" button. The dropdown listener checks the selected option and shows/hides the custom domain input field accordingly. Meanwhile, the "Get Started" button listener should redirect the user to the appropriate Shoppy product page based on the selected option. I have checked that the IDs used in the code match those defined in the HTML file and verified the logic inside the event listeners.
Inspected the console log for errors: I have looked at the console log for any errors or warnings, but I could not find anything useful. The console log seemed to show that all scripts were properly loaded.
```

Despite these efforts, the code still doesn't work as expected. The issue persists even though I have tried several approaches to fix it.